# Colab and gdown, folder in google drive to colab, stopped working, permission error?

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-colaboratory

Until yesterday I had my files in google drive and I used the following command in Colab to download the folder with all of them:

```
!gdown https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Ocm3YhQOqXepID60Hf5_L9uYnt8hAb4s -O /content/ --folder
```

today it is giving the following error:

"Access denied with the following error:
Cannot retrieve the public link of the file. You may need to change
the permission to 'Anyone with the link', or have had many accesses. "

The folder is accessible to anyone with the link. I've tried several forms of codes from the Internet and nothing works.

And my individual files (not folders), I downloaded until yesterday like this:

```
!gdown "1Pn1XNMYDPNzPoZ6MyeNnUiVGtrNEFDyQ"
```

Now it only works if you add "&confirm=t" next to the id:

```
!gdown "1Pn1XNMYDPNzPoZ6MyeNnUiVGtrNEFDyQ&confirm=t"
```

But the folder I can't find a way to download from the drive to the Colab.

Comment: You should consider using the google drive api itself instead of using the downlead link.  That link is not stable.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with reading in files, and here's my code that seemed to solve it for me:

```
file_id = '<file_id>'
url = f'https://drive.google.com/uc?id={file_id}'

gdown.download(url, '<name of file>', quiet=False)

pre_df = pd.read_csv('<name of file>')
```

This works for individual files, but for folders you might have to save it as a zip and download it in that way:

```
file_id = 'zip_file_id'
url = f'https://drive.google.com/uc?id={file_id}'
gdown.download(url, 'my_folder.zip', quiet=False)

with zipfile.ZipFile('my_folder.zip', 'r') as zip_ref:
    zip_ref.extractall('my_folder')
```

This downloads the folder as a file, and extracts it so you can access the files inside.